# Node.js how to make http get requests in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making http get request to some endpoint, let's say /bla-bla/{country}?page={page_number}, which returns me json with some stuff, including field total_pages. So i am looping countries, and for every country at first query page value is 1, it's return response where i read total_pages for this country, an then i need repeat request with page++ until it reaches total_pages, then next country and same operations for it. So i am noob in js and a i see that most libs dealing with http returns promises on request, or use callback, and i can't understand how to achieve my goal with promises chain or callback functions.Pls give some advise...

Comment: Promises make this task quite simple, have you actually tried anything yet?

Comment: i tried big chain of Promise.then().then() but it is obviously wrong way

Comment: Questions about code should show your actual code since that makes it a LOT easier for us to give you a specific and accurate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map over your requests:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
then await them with a Promise.all
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```
const requests = countries.map(country => {
  return fetch(`www.some-api.com/${country}/page=1`)
}

const responses = await Promise.all(requests)
```

Then if you want to use info returned from those requests you can basically do the same thing again (but with a reduce).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

```
const countryPageRequests = responses.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  // I am assuming data structure here

  const pages = []
  for (i = 1, i <= response.maxPages, i++) {
    pages.push(fetch(`www.some-api.com/${request.country}/page=${i}`))
  }

  return [...acc, ...pages];
}, [])

const countryPageResults = Promise.all(countryPageRequests);
```

Promise.all runs all of the promises concurrently, then you have an array of the results given to you. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot for you advise, will try it at morning

Comment: what does [...acc,...pages] means?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
It is the spread syntax. basically changing flattening both arrays into one.